# Unity3d restart current scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok so I am trying to restart the scene on R being pressed and for some reason, I am getting errors like, well in the unity console: "unexpected symbol '}' " and "parsing error". But then in Microsoft visual studio I'm getting "; expected". Any ideas of what's wrong with the following code?

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))  
        SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex
}
```

Comment: You really should get into the habit of using `{}`'s, even when there's only one expression. Omitting them can make for hard-to-notice bugs.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean sorry can you explain please @Basic

Comment: Hard to show in a single-line comment but... Instead of `if(condition) command;` You should use `if(condition) {command;}` Note the additional `{}`'s. See http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no/16530 for more information. It's not a hard-and-fast rule but it definitely reduces mistakes, especially if you're still finding your way.

Comment: oh thanks I get what you mean

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must ask the scene manager to load the scene using [LoadScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html)

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))  
    SceneManager.LoadScene( SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex ) ;
```

You were just retrieving the build index of the current scene.

Also, about yourcompilling error, you have forgotten the semi-colon at the end of the line ;)

Comment: You beat me too it. Also good that you added the semi-colon :D

Comment: @CasperPowell don't forget to mark this answer as the correct one ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can say that the code below might be the easiest method;

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
```

Answer (score -2):

just close the window and restart unity application, simple as that

Comment: Expand, explain why.

Comment: @howdodoit, your answer is out of context (probably you're joking).