# How can I restart my game when game over?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a 3d flappy bird game in unity and I can not figure out how to restart the game when the bird hits a Colum. I'm doing it in C#.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer you question: [Unity Restart current scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644156/unity3d-restart-current-scene/41644224)

Answer (score 0):

You can restart the game by just load again the game scene

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("game_scene");
```

Comment: thanks but I was wondering what the code was for actually making it do some thing when it hits the colum.

Comment: i don't know with 3D object, but as far as i know in unity 2D if your GameObject has Collider Component. There is a function called OnColliderEnter2D() with a Collision parameter. That function could be triggered when your GameObject touches another GameObject with a collider too. Then you could simply add a condition when it hits the colum and restart the scene

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reload the scene with SceneManager.LoadScene.
Although a better option might just be creating a function that restarts everything for you without reloading the scene by generating a new level and resetting player position and statistics.

Answer (score 0):

#### What you need?

1. Make sure you include the sceneManager api
2. Making a `restartGame()` function.
3. Calling the function when the bird bird hits a Colum.

#### The restartGame() code:

```
public Void restartGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Your game scene name");
}
```

If you didn't understand how to use the methods(functinos) [check this](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_methods.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can load it into a new scene using the Load Scene method